# How to set base address of a matrix?

Tags: c, embedded

I want to set the base address of a matrix of float at a precise place in my memory (embedded DSP development)

I'd like to do something like this, which is not working :

```
// volatile because of the DMA filling the array automatically
// base address is 0x80000000
volatile float example_two[100][2] = (volatile float *)0x80000000;
```

I know I can do it for a pointer like this, but I'll loose the array size ([100][2]):

```
// volatile because of the DMA filling the array automatically
// base address is 0x80000000
volatile float *example_one = (volatile float *)0x80000000;
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: While the provided answers may be a suitable solution for you and are portable across compilers, must compilers support extensions or linker directives to do this.  For an answer that uses that option, you'd have to specify your tool chain and possibly target architecture.  Some toolchains make it easy; GCC is a little cumbersome/ https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
volatile float (*example_two)[2] = (volatile float (*)[2]) 0x80000000;
```

This declaration allows you to use `example_two` as if it had been declared with `float example_two[100][2]`. For example, `example_two[i][j]` refers to element `j` of row `i`. By creating a pointer to arrays of two elements, this omits the `[100]` information from the type, but that is generally not needed.

Another option is to write:

```
volatile float (*example_two)[100][2] = (volatile float (*)[100][2]) 0x80000000;
```

This includes the full type information, but then it must be dereferenced to be used, as in `(*example_two)[i][j]`. This is more cumbersome.

Comment: Your first option is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *allocate* memory at a fixed address, you must use non-standard ways and also modify the linker script. This is compiler/linker specific.

If the memory is already allocated at that position and you know for a fact that it is of type `float [100][2]`, or of no type at all (untouched by compiler), then you can do use an array pointer:

```
volatile float (*example_two)[100][2];
example_two = (volatile float(*)[100][2]) 0x80000000UL;
```

In case of gcc, always disable strict aliasing in embedded sytems, just to be sure the compiler won't go haywire when for example reading a DMA buffer. `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: The memory is actually reserved and the linker cannot allocate anything in it, +1 for this explanation

Answer (score -1):

If you take these statements as in c language,
`volatile float *example_one = (volatile float *)0x80000000;`
here you make a pointer point to a location that you specify.
where as the following statement,
`volatile float example_two[100][2]`
creates an array. there is a memory allocation happening. So they are different statements.
You can create a pointer to an array in this case and try as,
`volatile float (*example_two)[100][2] = (volatile float *)0x80000000;`
You need to access the data then as `(*example_two)[i][j]`

Answer (score -1):

Try (or don't try) this ugly `#define` trick

```
#define example_two (*donttrythisathome)

float example_two[100][2] = (void*)0xDEADBEEF;
example_two[42][0] = example_two[42][1] = -0.42;
```

See working example on https://ideone.com/7c6dJ9